# How to join two tables such that same column from both the tables are not repeated?

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables

```
Table 1: employee
+----+---------+--------+--------+------+-------+------+----------+
| No | Name    | Salary | Zone   | Age  | Grade | Dept | HireDate |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------+-------+------+----------+
|  1 | Mukul   |  30000 | West   |   28 | A     |   10 | NULL     |
|  2 | Kritika |  35000 | Centre |   30 | A     |   10 | NULL     |
|  3 | Naveen  |  35200 | West   |   40 | B     |   20 | NULL     |
|  4 | Uday    |  41800 | North  |   38 | C     |   30 | NULL     |
|  5 | Nupur   |  32000 | East   |   26 | B     |   20 | NULL     |
|  6 | Moksh   |  37000 | South  |   28 | B     |   10 | NULL     |
|  7 | Shelly  |  36000 | North  |   26 | A     |   30 | NULL     |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------+-------+------+----------+

Table 2:department
+------+---------+--------+--------+------+
| Dept | Dname   | Minsal | Maxsal | HoD  |
+------+---------+--------+--------+------+
|   10 | Sales   |  25000 |  32000 |    1 |
|   20 | Finance |  30000 |  50000 |    5 |
|   30 | Admin   |  25000 |  40000 |    7 |
+------+---------+--------+--------+------+
```

Suppose I want to display details of all the employees who work in the Sales department.
I tried `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM employee AS A
INNER JOIN department AS B
ON A.Dept = B.Dept AND B.Dname = "Sales";
```

This displayed this table

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+------+-------+------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------+------+
| No | Name    | Salary | Zone   | Age  | Grade | Dept | HireDate | Dept | Dname | Minsal | Maxsal | HoD  |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------+-------+------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------+------+
|  1 | Mukul   |  30000 | West   |   28 | A     |   10 | NULL     |   10 | Sales |  25000 |  32000 |    1 |
|  2 | Kritika |  35000 | Centre |   30 | A     |   10 | NULL     |   10 | Sales |  25000 |  32000 |    1 |
|  6 | Moksh   |  37000 | South  |   28 | B     |   10 | NULL     |   10 | Sales |  25000 |  32000 |    1 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------+-------+------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------+------+
```

As you can see the Dept column is displayed twice.
So here are my questions
1. How to display same name columns only once?
2. Instead of `INNER JOIN` how else this can be done i.e Any better ways to do this?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What output do you expect?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @juergend I have edited the question and included the output except the Dept column is displayed twice. I want it to be displayed only once.

Comment: `SELECT A.*, B.Dname, B.Minsal, B.Maxsal, B.HoD FROM ...`

Comment: @Nick Yes, this did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
select A.No, A.Name, A.Salary, A.Zone, A.Age, A.Grade, A.Dept, A.HireDate,
   B.Dname, B.Minsal, B.Maxsal, B.HoD
(...)
```

Inner join is the right way to join. No problems on this side.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting everything with `*` you need to specify the columns you want. You can also limit the `*` to all columns of a single table. Example:

```
SELECT e.*, d.Dname, d.HoD  
FROM employee AS e
INNER JOIN department AS d ON e.Dept = d.Dept 
WHERE d.Dname = "Sales";
```